# Entity Framework Core - Changing Database Schema at runtime without running migration

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core 5 application with Entity Framework (code first) with migrations and Azure SQL database.

I want to run two separate applications on same DB with different data. I want to have test and demo application. My idea was to change schema for each application. One application will have schema "test." and another one "demo.".

I tried to do this with this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#table-schema)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("demo");
}
```

Problem is that I need to run Add-Migration with this approach. And I don't want to do that.

There is also another way that I didn't try. Described [here](https://medium.com/@pawel.gerr/entity-framework-core-changing-database-schema-at-runtime-dcf1211768c6)

Problem there is that I need to create EntityConfiguration for each Entity and I don't want to do this neither.

I want to set schema globally for all tables at once.

Is there a way how to do this without creating new migrations? Or is there a better way without changing scheme?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you.
Create custom migration where you could inject schema

https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/changing-db-migration-schema-at-runtime-in-2-1/

```
ppublic partial class Initial_Migration : Migration
{
  private readonly IDbContextSchema _schema;

  public Initial_Migration(IDbContextSchema schema)
  {
    _schema = schema ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(schema));
  }

  protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
  {
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable("Products",
                        table => new { Id = table.Column<Guid>() },
                        constraints: table => table.PrimaryKey("PK_Products", x => x.Id),
                        schema: _schema.Schema);
  }

  protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
  {
    migrationBuilder.DropTable("Products", _schema.Schema);
  }
}
```